# Jupyter notebook MATLAB kernel: Runs, but does not display output

Tags: matlab, jupyter-notebook, output

The issue is as shown in the image below. The kernel runs but the output is not displayed.
For installation, I followed the steps under 'Python side configuration' and 'MATLAB side configuration' [here](https://am111.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jmatlab_install.html).
[image]

Have tried the following:

1. All other kernels work normally
2. The issue persists in both Firefox and Chrome

Edit: There were no issues in the installation of the python engine.

```
sudo python3 setup.py install

[sudo] password for tinkidinki:
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
copying build/lib/matlab/engine/_arch.txt -> /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/matlab/engine
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/matlabengineforpython-R2020b.egg-info
Writing /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/matlabengineforpython-R2020b.egg-info
```

Comment: I'm assuming you installed the Python engine in the extern/engines/python subdirectory and everything went well (no error message in the terminal)?

Comment: @mfevre89, yes, everything went well. Edited the answer to post the output

Comment: Which os did this problem occur on?

Comment: @CasperDijkstra Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

- Most likely your antivirus program is blocking the output (e.g. Adaware antivirus often causes this problem).
- If this is not the case: sometimes the output is shown in the command prompt window instead of in the Jupyter notebook, check if this is the case.
- Try restarting the kernel in kernel option (yup, more of a workaround...)